# Cox Regression used for business churn/ lifetime value

Tags: multiple-regression, cox-model, churn

Cox regression seems useful as a broad strokes model for measuring survival/ churn of a subscription-based product/ account lifetime estimate -- and the broad factors that might influence the survival curve (and area under the curve for estimated lifespan).

Unlike typical human survival data however where there's generally a live/ die binary ---

In business terms, unlike with an account "dying" -- the living accounts can "grow" in terms of monthly/ annual revenue.

In other words, if one were building a model to predict "lifetime value" (estimated lifespan x (value per t ) .... would one combine a linear regression model to estimate "growth/ value" over time ... to combine with 'estimated lifespan remaining' essentially?

This seems like a fairly common business problem. I've been playing around with a few things -- and the Cox portion seems straightforward. In terms of estimating lifespan based on a few key variables & current age --

The other part seems complicated. Like sure, you can do a very basic 'any account that survives grows 10% per month" -- but in reality there are many measurable variables that would impact this prediction as well.

I suppose the models wouldn't be combined per se.... there would just be a Cox model for lifespan ... a regression model (or some sort of time series) -- for estimated 'Revenue per T' ... and then essentially a cross-product of some sort of the outputs...

Answer (score 0):

easiest to use a discrete time survival model, aka any probabilistic classifier (eg logistic regression or xgboost) , which predicts probably of churn in next period, given didn't churn until then.

Then you can calculate any arbitrary payoff as the sum of probability of churning at each period x payoff at each period (for example)